# multiple columns in mysql indices

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

suppose I have the following indices (Output from SHOW INDEXES):

```
Table, Non_unique, Key_name, Seq_in_index, Column_name, Collation, Cardinaity, etc etc
'tn', 1, 'Index1', 1, 'fid', 'A', 366, , '', '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'tn', 1, 'Index1', 2, 'obj_type', 'A', 366, , '', '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'tn', 1, 'Index1', 3, 'obj_id', 'A', 366, , '', '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'tn', 1, 'Index1', 4, 'rule', 'A', 366, , '', '', 'BTREE', '', ''
```

Notice that Index1 contains 4 columns in it...

Will doing this allow me to obtain all the performance benefits of having just one index for one column (say fid)?

In other words, what's the difference as well as what's the benefit/setbacks of having such multiple column in one index as opposed to having only one column per index....IE what's the difference between having the setup above versus having the setup below

```
Table, Non_unique, Key_name, Seq_in_index, Column_name, Collation, Cardinaity, etc etc
'tn', 1, 'Index1', 1, 'fid', 'A', 366, , '', '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'tn', 1, 'Index2', 1, 'obj_type', 'A', 366, , '', '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'tn', 1, 'Index3', 1, 'obj_id', 'A', 366, , '', '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'tn', 1, 'Index4', 1, 'rule', 'A', 366, , '', '', 'BTREE', '', ''
```

Notice that in the above scenario, each column has its own index

Which one would be faster/more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multi-column index could in some cases replace the need for separate individual indexes.  It really depends on knowing how the table is going to be queried which would determine what is most appropriate.

If you have an index on say columns A, B, and C (in that order).  You will get optimized index performance if you use any of the following combinations of fields in your WHERE clause for example.

```
A
A, B
A, B, C
```

Note that in order to use the index when looking at columns B or C, you must also utilize the other column(s) to the left of it in the index. These also have to be referenced in the correct order of the index.

For more detailed information look here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: Another question...do the same rules apply for Primary Key Indices with multiple columns (ie where A, B, C are all primary keys within the same index)

Comment: Yes, but obviously in the case of a compound primary key, I would think you would ALWAYS be using the entire index on joins/filters, since jointly they would be the unique record identifier for the table.